# Запустить веб приложения на телефоне во время Debug-а

Tags: android, отладка, blazor, blazor-server-side

> а как можно, тестировать онлайн во время деБага ?

какой есть вариант web **Blazor Server** запустить с Визуал Студио на телефоне во время **Debug-а** ?

Чтоб протестировать веб приложение на телефоне *у меня получается после его публикации*,

1. открыла FireWall ([Межсетевой экран](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD)) в настройках компьютера
2. поставила телефон на ту же сеть что и IIS (там же опубликовано приложение)
3. ввела (http) ip + порт и приложение открылось с телефона => ок

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: @eri а вы сами пробовали, у вас получилось ? просто я уже и телефон сменила, и каждый раз этот док открываю, думаю может что пропустила, но не получается. все время пишет не удается получить доступ к сайту. Что я пропускаю ? я и localHost пробовала, и Ip, и даже подумала может Брандма́уэр и его открыла и пробовала и http/https тоже. Ну все равно приходится публиковать приложение, чтоб протестировать на телефоне. Док так написан аккуратно и вроде все ясно...какая деталь от меня там прячется ☹️

Comment: Вряд ли eri пробовал, учитывая, что он пишет на питоне. Что до самой проблемы, скорее всего отладочный IIS в Visual Studio слушает запросы только на localhost, поэтому со внешнего устройства к нему не подключиться. Попробуйте что-нибудь из этого: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364468/8674428

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight а то, что я проект запускаю во время дебаг не iis , а просто запустить проект и выбираю название проекта => запустить из визуаль студио, это все равно принуждает настраивать iis ? зы=> по ссылке прошла, запуталась там

Comment: Я сам не специалист по ASP.NET, но в моем понимании отладка в Visual Studio использует особый урезанный IIS, который называется IIS Express. Поэтому настройки надо делать именно для него. По ссылке видимо лучше начать со второго ответа, в котором "три шага".

Comment: по вопросу я подумал что клиент надо отдебужить..

Comment: @eri клиент это веб сторона ? да, так и есть. Приложение Блазор СерверСайд это веб клиент, только в режиме отладки. Ссылка классная, что вы отправили, все аккуратно расписано, но что то пока у меня еще в режиме настройки...по другой ссылке прошла, там тоже че то запуталась...вообщем пока что ищу

Answer (score 2):

Используйте **[Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)**

1. Откройте аккаунт [на сайте](https://%20https://dashboard.ngrok.com/login), есть опция зайти от аккаунта гитхаб
2. Заполните анкету (для чего используете итп)

3.а Скачайте зип, распакуйте и используйте (если выдало ошибку перейдите (может ваша среда не имеет доступа к данному интерфейсу) => к 3.б)

3.б Установите [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install#individual) Выберите Individual
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Введите в PowerShell (запустив от имени администратора) `Get-ExecutionPolicy`
Затем скопируйте комманду и также введите в консоль (сама комманда на странице, по ссылке выше), проверьте установлено ли все верно `choco -?`

4. [Ngrok](https://chocolatey.org/install#individual) => следуйте коммандам для установки
   `choco install ngrok` => `ngrok config add-authtoken ....`
5. Запустите ваше приложение с VisualStudio, скопируйте ссылку и введите комманду `ngrok http http://localhost:8080` заменив http://localhost:8080 на вашу ссылку.
6. Выберите пункт Forwarding => там указана ссылка на ваш 'туннель'
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также от Визуаль Студио есть обновления, [вот блог](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dev-tunnels-a-game-changer-for-mobile-developers/)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с [VisualStudio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dev-tunnels-a-game-changer-for-mobile-developers/) вообще прост :

1. Создаем 'туннель'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Он может быть

   а. Private = только с вашего почтового ящика сможете входить на других устройствах

   б. Professional = почтовые ящики с одним и тем же доменом

   в. Public = не рекомендуется, тк это просто публичный тоннель

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. После получения сообщения о удачном создании

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Выбираем из списка наш тоннель / по умолчанию при создании он сразу делает его активным

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и теперь доступна ссылка (при запуске проекта) (генерируется некий токен уникальный), которую можно открыть на Андроид во время дебага. При первом запуске (если тоннель Private) у вас попросят войти в ваш почтовый ящик, который указан в Visual Studio